# Iphone view got cut off

Tags: iphone, view, landscape

My landscape subview is being cut off by the previous view, why is it like that?

Cut off as in the previous view is at the bottom part around 1/3 quarter of the screen even when the new subview is added. Something like this > http://i41.photobucket.com/albums/e253/welzenn99/123.png

Answer (score 0):

you need to set that view's frame in

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
```

OR in

```
 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the method where you tell the subview to come out ([self.view addSubview:someView.view];) add

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
    //rotate to landscape
    someView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
}
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    //rotate to portrait 
    isomeView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
}
```

worked for me. good luck